# DayRound Rounding Values:No difference between "Preceding" and "Following"?

Tags: date-and-time

On Mathematica 10.0.1 both

```
DayRound[{1980, 2, 29}, "EndOfMonth", "Preceding"]
```

and

```
DayRound[{1980, 2, 29}, "EndOfMonth", "Following"]
```

produce

```
DateObject[List[1980,2,29],Rule[CalendarType,"Gregorian"]]
```

Is that correct? I would expect that the first one would produce the January 31 and the later one to produce March 31.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented behavior. From the docs on [DayRound >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DayRound.html):

In `DayRound[date, daytype, rounding]`

> If *date* is of *daytype*, `DayRound` has no effect.

So, since `{1980, 2, 29}` an `"EndOfMonth"` day, its "rounded" form is itself. And

```
DayRound[{1980, 2, 28}, "EndOfMonth","Preceding"]
```

return `DateObject[{1980, 1, 31}, CalendarType -> "Gregorian"]` as expected. However, you need

```
DayRound[{1980, 3, 1}, "EndOfMonth","Following"]
```

to get `DateObject[{1980, 3, 31}, CalendarType -> "Gregorian"]`.

Comment: thanks. Yet I still struggle to understand the logic of "Preceding" and "Following" having no effect.

Comment: @iav, i agree it does feel puzzling. Perhaps it helps to try to think of `"Preceding"` and `"Following"` in the _weak inequality_  (`LessEqual` and `GreaterEqual`) sense.